# how to check like condition in if loop

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I need to validate a string variable contains a string validation like below. how to do it in sybase ase?

```
if @text like '%test%' 
begin
end
```

i tried with this statement and i get Function LIKE is invoked with wrong number of arguments. as i am new to sybase not sure its proper syntax.

Updated the actual code and error print.

[image]

and the version says as 'Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP03 ....'

Comment: assuming you have something between the `begin` and `end` (eg, `print 'yes'`) then there's nothing wrong with this construct so I'm wondering if you're really using the Sybase ASE product and/or what you're using aa a front-end to run this piece of code; I'd suggest updating the question with more details, eg, output from `select @@version`, a complete, minimal, reproducible example and the complete output from running the example code block in the `isql` command line tool

Comment: @markp-fuso, i have updated the question with the details you have asked. any help please?

Comment: It could be the preceding line(s). It could be the variable's data type. There are too many possibilities. That's why you should always cut away irrelevant code, leaving only what is necessary to reproduce the problem; [mre]. (Please read the link.)

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @MatBailie, yes it works. its data type conversion problem. i get it from your hint. thank you so much. this code works well after i do convert `if convert(varchar(20), @loan_origination_type, 112) like '%LOT2%'`.